# Number of open sets in a topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a set with 4 elements. Is it possible to have a topology on $X$ with 14 open sets?

Comment: 16 is the very most it could have. ($2^4 = 16$ would be the discrete topology.) So you might try fooling around with 14 and seeing if you can get the other two just by the axioms.

Answer (score 4):

Hints:

1) If each singleton is open, then the topology is the discrete one. So assume not every singleton is open.

2) Since we are allowed to miss exactly two subsets from the list of open sets, and there are four singletons, without loss of generality, $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$ are open.

3) Of the remaining $\{3\}$ and $\{4\}$ at least one must not be open. Assume neither is open. But then, to have fourteen elements in the topology, the topology must be $\mathcal P (X)-\{\{3\},\{4\}\}$. But this is not a topology (find two sets in it the intersect to give $\{3\}$.

4) So, without loss of generality, $\{3\}$ is also open and thus $\{4\}$ is not open. But note that you can find three subsets such that any two intersect to give $\{4\}$, and so, since you are only allowed to miss one of those, you can't obtain a topology with 14 elements on a four element set.

Answer (score 1):

We do most of the problem, leaving the last step to you.

If singletons are open, everything is open.

Suppose that $\{1\}$ is not open. Then $\{1,2,3\}$, $\{1,2,4\}$, and $\{1,3,4\}$ cannot all be open, else their intersection would be.

We may assume that $\{1,2,3\}$ is not open. Show this is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there are exactly two non-open sets, say $S$ and $T$, and that at least one of them, say $S = \{a\}$, is a 1-set.  Each 1-set $\{a\}$ can be written as the intersection of 2-sets in three ways:

$$ \{a, b\}\cap \{a,c\} = \{a\}\\
\{a, b\}\cap \{a,d\} = \{a\}\\
\{a, c\}\cap \{a,d\} = \{a\}
$$

If $S =\{a\}$ is non-open, then at most one of the 2-sets is non-open, and then at least one of the intersections above is an intersection of two open sets, so $S$ is open, which is a contradiction.

So all of the 1-sets are open. But then the topology is discrete and all 16 subsets of $X$ are  open.